# Exception instantiating FloatBuffer[]

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an array of 144 FloatBuffers so I can easily access each one using an integer to pick which one. No, I don't mean a FloatBuffer 144 long. I'm investigating using a class to contain all the FloatBuffers, but it'll take some time. Any thoughts?

I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

on this line, no matter what method I use to try to instantiate the new FloatBuffer INTO the array:

```
    for(int i=0; i<144;i++){
    vbuffers[i] = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(buffervolume*7);
    }
```

I also tried this and got the same error:

```
        vbuffers[i]=FloatBuffer.allocate(buffervolume*7);
```

Here is the full relevant code:

```
public class myclass {

public FloatBuffer[] vbuffers;

public myclass(){
    vbuffers=new FloatBuffer[chunklimit*chunklimit*4];
    for(int i=0; i<144;i++){
    vbuffers[i] = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(chunkvolume*7);
    }
}
}
```

I would like to add that I ended up using one large FloatBuffer and glbuffersubdata to manage my data and got really great results.

Comment: My guess is the vbuffers[i]. Check your math to make sure chunklimit*chunklimit*4 is large enough. Use the debugger to see what value of i it is complaining about.

Comment: I would check your FloatBuffers use direct memory in native byte order.  Using heap or direct memory in big endian can be much slower. (Unless you need them in big-endian)

Comment: Something wrong with `new float[144]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception strongly suggests that `vbuffers` is a zero-length array. Check that `chunklimit` is non-zero.

In general, when you have code like this:

```
vbuffers = new FloatBuffer[chunklimit*chunklimit*4];
for(int i = 0; i < 144; i++) {
    vbuffers[i] = ...
```

there's a risk that `chunklimit*chunklimit*4` won't be the same as `144`, resulting in errors.

It is usually a better idea to use the size of the array in the `for` loop:

```
vbuffers = new FloatBuffer[chunklimit*chunklimit*4];
for(int i = 0; i < vbuffers.length; i++) {
    vbuffers[i] = ...
```

Comment: This worked to get the arrays going, but unfortunately the end result didn't work with my program (extremely inefficient to draw from 144 buffers), and didn't want to read data properly. I'm not quite sure why 144 didn't work since that is exactly the length. But this was right, thank you.